# text wrap around image in rails

Tags: css, haml

I'm trying to have an image on the left hand side of the page and then the text beside it (to it's right) on two lines.

At the moment my code is:

```
.review_author
- if review.bride.has_avatar?
  = filepicker_image_tag review.bride.avatar, w:50, h:50, fit: 'clip'
  = "Posted by"
  =link_to review.author, bride_reviews_path(review.bride), style: 'color: #E62B8A'
  = "on #{review.created_at.strftime("#{review.created_at.day.ordinalize}" " %b %Y")}"
  - if review.bride.wedding_date
    = "Wedding date: #{review.bride.wedding_date.to_time.strftime('%b %Y')}"
```

With this, the two line of text 'Posted by x on x date' and "wedding date:.." are in one line together. And this aligns with the baseline of the image rather than being at the top or center.

So, the question is - how to I get the text to lie in two lines on the right of the thumbnail?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS issue more than a Rails issue (the fact it uses Rails outputted data is co-incidental)

---

**CSS**

I believe you're looking for [css inline-blocks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/):

(I'll write pure css / html for you):

**http://jsfiddle.net/5Yk6e/**

```
<div class="review_author">
    <% if review.bride.has_avater? %>
        <%= filepicker_image_tag review.bride.avatar, w:50, h:50, fit: 'clip', class: 'avatar' %>
        <div class="info">
            <span>"Posted By:"</span>
            <%= link_to review.author, bride_reviews_path(review.bride), style: 'color: #E62B8A' %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

.review_author {
    display: block;
    background: #ff0;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.review_author > * { vertical-align:middle; }
.avatar {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.info     { display: inline-block;}
.info > * { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add in some extra classes like so:

```
.review_author
  - if review.bride.has_avatar?
    .review_image
      = filepicker_image_tag review.bride.avatar, w:50, h:50, fit: 'clip'
    .review_info
      %p
        = "Posted by"
        =link_to review.author, bride_reviews_path(review.bride), style: 'color: #E62B8A'
      %p
        = "on #{review.created_at.strftime("#{review.created_at.day.ordinalize}" " %b %Y")}"
        - if review.bride.wedding_date
          = "Wedding date: #{review.bride.wedding_date.to_time.strftime('%b %Y')}"
```

Then style them like so: http://jsfiddle.net/JRLzz/

Comment: Rich Peck's css is much nicer than mine, but you get the idea.

Comment: Also, notice the indentation - `if` statements must be nested for the conditions to also be nested.